# Java setResizable(false) changes the window size (swing)

Tags: java, swing, window

I have a strange problem. I am using the null layout for a window (= JFrame and on windows) and if I use setResizable (false) the window size gets bigger (to right and bottom, around 10 pixels I would say). I do not know why.

The two println's return the same sizes, what is strange, also...

```
mainWnd.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
mainWnd.setTitle(wndTitle);
mainWnd.setBounds(wndPosX, wndPosY, wndWidth, wndHeight);
System.out.println(mainWnd.getHeight() + mainWnd.getWidth());
mainWnd.setResizable(false);
System.out.println(mainWnd.getHeight() + mainWnd.getWidth());
```

Does somebody has an idea? Why does the window gets resized?

UPDATE: 
Same thing here (compile it with and without the setResizable and than you can see it, if you overlap the windows):

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Main
{
    private static JFrame mainWnd = null;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        mainWnd = new JFrame();

        mainWnd.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainWnd.setTitle("asda");
        mainWnd.setBounds(50, 50, 300, 300);

        mainWnd.setResizable(false);

        mainWnd.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You will get better and quicker answers if you show a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: there is an example, cant paste the rest, cause a xml-parser works behind it and much more...
and the problem just happens with the setResizable call

Comment: I can't reproduce the behaviour. So try to get rid of all the unnecessary parts and post a compilable and runnable example that has the behaviour you mention.

Comment: does the 'xml-parser' or that 'much more' have any impact on the size of of the window?

Comment: the jframe is a member and setBounds() only gets called in the constructor. as i said i cant paste more, as there are many classes that i do not own. anyway, i see that is difficult to help, but i thought somebody might had the same problem...

Comment: strange indeed - can reproduce (on vista), LAF doesn't seem to make a difference, the window decoration appear to have the same size ... no idea as to the why ..

Comment: Seeing a similar bug in Linux Gnome (AdoptJDK 11). Tracking the container events when frame becomes visible, contents pane is first painted 10 and 7 pixels off, then another resize event comes and display is correct. Annoying visual glitch. Perhaps related.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It does not change on my example, so you must have something else that causes your issue:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test4 {

    protected static void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
        frame.setBounds(0, 0, 300, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        System.err.println(frame.getSize());
        frame.setResizable(false);
        System.err.println(frame.getSize());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                initUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

EDIT/UPDATE:

Somehow insets are incorrect when you set the resizable to false (at least on Windows 7 and JDK 6). Somehow they change from 30,8,8,8 to 25,3,3,3 although the border (which is painted by the OS) stays actually the same. Since insets are part of the bounds of the Frame, the frame is actually too big (visually) when it is not resizable. For me it looks like there is a bug in the computed insets when the frame is not resizable.

Comment: i think you should start both windows, then you see that the not resizable is bigger!

Comment: Somehow insets are incorrect when you set the resizable to false (at least on Windows 7 and JDK 6). Somehow they change from 30,8,8,8 to 25,3,3,3 although the border stays actually the same. Since insets are part of the bounds of the Frame, the frame is actually too big (visually) when it is not resizable. For me it looks like there is a bug in the computed insets when the frame is not resizable.

Comment: nice trackdown (in your comment) - you might consider to move it into the answer, so I can vote on it :-)

Comment: @Guillaume Polet Sorry this is quite a necro but I came across this while trying to fix this issue. The solution is to use: getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400)); setResizable(false); pack(); In that order, so you have to call pack after you setResizable(false). Could you add it so others could get to the solution faster? Thanks!

Comment: @deadfire19 This doesn't work for me - though I would also love to be able to toggle between risizable states without my frame changing size by 10 in width and height as well as having it move a little bit ...

Answer (score 6):

If you set setResizable false before setting the bounds, you will not have the problem. as Gergely Szilagyi stated before, you are getting rid of the scrollbars, but the size of the window is locked and therefore you end up with 9 or 10 pixels of extra space in the frame. I just had the same problem. thanks for the help.

Comment: No, it keeps giving me the difference between two JFrames.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the L&F setting the resizable(false/true) might change the window border decorations. No maximize, no resize arrow. That itself can change the size.

Comment: In my case, with no other L&F set, e.g., with default look and feel, it changes windows size too.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
frame.setResizable(false);
```

to:

```
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            frame.setResizable(false);
        }
    });
```

Comment: The problem persists. It's not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well I have met this problem and it is a Look & Feel problem...

Why the resizable frame has an insets of (5, 5, 5, 5)? It leads me to think that **make it resizable adds some extra component around the frame, like... some kind of "handler" to drag to resize**?

And then I found that if we use default Java Metal l&f and set `setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true)`, the handler will be painted and thus, the frame will not change size. But in Nimbus, Motif and Windows L&F this point is not implemented, so it's a bug. I will report it.

My own question and my answer with GIF is here:

[Swing - setResizable(true) make JFrame title bar higher and window size smaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44303746/swing-setresizabletrue-make-jframe-title-bar-higher-and-window-size-smaller/44313182#44313182)

Answer (score 0):

So far the best patch for this annoying issue is the following. Doesn't matter where you call the `setResizable(false)` method. Just add this piece of code after you `setVisible(true)`.

```
private void sizeBugPatch() {
    while (frame.getWidth() > yourWidth) {
        frame.pack();
    }
}
```

Where `yourWidth` is the *width* you've set in any of the possible ways, either manually or by overriding `setPreferredSize` methods. The explanation is quite easy, `frame.pack()` seems to reset `frame.setResizable(boolean b)` somehow. You could use an `if` instead of the `while` loop but I prefer `while` to exclude the case the window would still be extra-sized even after a second `pack()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a 2 JFrame subclasses defined.  If I run the problem frame in a standalone app, the frame size is correct.  If I run both frames in a standalone app, the problem frame is still larger.  I did setResizable(false) before pack, and I still get the problem.  My workaround was to change the layout to BorderLayout and plop the (image) panel in the center, then did the setResizable.