# JFrame size and pack() issues

Tags: java, swing, jframe

My first, and more simple problem, is that my JFrame size gets messed up when I set resizable to false. For excample, this works:

```
setSize((this.mapSize * tileSize) + 16, (this.mapSize * tileSize) + 16);
```

but this doesn't:

```
setSize((this.mapSize * tileSize) + 16, (this.mapSize * tileSize) + 16);
setResizable(false);
```

How can I fix it so that I can disable re-sizing without altering the positions of the contents of the frame.

My second question is how I can improve the runtime of the code. I have isolated the majority of time taken happens while it is in the `pack()` block. I sometimes have over a million tiles that I need to draw, so it can take over an hour to do that alone. Here is my code (Note: Tile is just a JPanel with a background color)

```
    setLayout(new FlowLayout(0, 0, 0));
    System.out.println("Generating...");
    new Terrain(this.mapSize);
    System.out.println("Done \nAdding Tiles...");
    for (double[] row : Terrain.tileData) {
        for (double d : row) {
            int v = (int) (20 - d / 500);
            if(v < 0) {
                v = 0;
            }
            else if (v > 20){
                v = 20;
            }
            add(new Tile(v, tileSize));
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Done \nPacking...");
    pack();
    System.out.println("Done \nRepainting...");
    repaint();
    System.out.println("Done");
```

Comment: Better think about using `Graphics2D` to draw your million tiles, then. Use double buffering and make sure to optimize away anything off-screen.

Comment: For your first question: [check out this answer (Set resizable changes the window size)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225144/java-setresizablefalse-changes-the-window-size-swing/11225254#11225254). For your second question, provide a bit more info so that we can provide better answer.

Comment: @AlexR Could you give an example

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Ok, I'm going to add the code that adds the tiles to my question

Comment: @Asourcious Does the [official Java 2D tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) shed any light?

Comment: Btw, if you use Swing correctly, double buffering is useless as it is built-in with Swing. But, as already mentioned, provide more code so that we can provided better answers