# White bars in the right and bottom sides of a canvas after a JOptionPane confirmDialog?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

So guys, using a `JOptionPane` to ask the user if the app should update or not, and after which I get these white bars in the bottom and right sides of my canvas. Tried removing the autoupdate thing and works fine. Here's my code

```
GameUtils.init();
String version = AutoUpdate.checkForUpdates();
if (Double.parseDouble(version) > AutoUpdate.VERSION) {
    AutoUpdate.update(version);            
    JFrame frame = null;

    try
    {
        frame = new JFrame(GameUtils.data.getString("title"));
    } catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    frame.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 500));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    GameUtils.instance = new Game(frame);

    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {
        @Override
        public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            GameUtils.instance.stop();
            System.exit(0);
        }

        @Override
        public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {


        }

        @Override
        public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {

        }
    });
    frame.setVisible(true);
    GameUtils.instance.start();
}
```

[image: here is how it looks] Coordinating system works normally
I want it to look this way [image: I want it to look this way]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] not only a code snippet, we don't know how `AutoUpdate.checkForUpdates();` or `Game(frame);` looks like. This will lead to better and faster answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem you noticed when i use setResizable(false) and pack() method in a JFrame.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225144/java-setresizablefalse-changes-the-window-size-swing) you can find an answer which describes the problem, but i didn't find a solution that works for me.

In my applications i use a sort of "trick" if needed: i check if the contentPane preferred width is equal to his effective width, if not i recall pack() method.

Something like:

```
for(int i=0;i<5 && contentPane.getPreferredSize().width!=contentPane.getSize().width;i++) frame.pack();
```

Of course this isn't a really good solution, but it works for me and if you use a parameter to limit the maximum number of times that pack() should occur, you don't risk to block your gui...