# JFrame JPanel refreshing/updating/repainting

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Edit: some sort of refresh is being sent when I drag the borders, I need to figure that out and manually send that same refresh.

- Please note I have tried using revalidate() and repaint().

When using JFrame and JPanel to display a frame, I'm trying to make it so the size of the frame is easily mutable.

What I'm trying to do is make a switch so I can toggle between a "small view" and a "big view".

However, there is a white bar appearing on the panel's content when trying to:

- open frame... (by default is big size)
- set to small size
- set to big size again
- set to small size again (this is when the white bar appears)
  (refer to the comments in the main method)

Here is a picture of the white bar that appears at the bottom of the contents on the frame:[image: white bar bottom of game]

**Also, a big note is that the white bar disappears and reloads/refreshes the content properly when you drag the border (even if you drag it just a small amount)**

```
public class FrameTest {
    private static FrameTest instance;

    JFrame clientFrame

    JPanel client_panel;

    private void openFrames() {
            JclientFrame = new JFrame("727 Deob");
            clientFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            client_panel = new JPanel();
            client_panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            client_panel.add(new Applet());
            client_panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(765, 555));
            clientFrame.getContentPane().add(client_panel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
            clientFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            clientFrame.pack();
            clientFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       instance = new FrameTest();
       instance.openFrames();

       instance.setDimensions(true); //works absolutely fine!
       instance.setDimensions(false); //continues to work absolutely fine!
       instance.setDimensions(true); //now the white bar at the bottom appears


    }


    public void setDimensions(boolean smallType) {
        int width = 765;
        int height = smallType ? 530 : 577;
        clientFrame.setSize(width, height);

        //tried using revalidate() and repaint() here on the frame, the frame contents AND the panel... NO LUCK, white bars still aren't fixed.
    }


}
```

Comment: I believe that you have errors in your code. `BorderLayout.START_END` does not seems a valid constraint, and `instance = new FrameTest().openFrames();` does not return an instance of FrameTest. Can you provide a working code?

Comment: @fhofmann, It should be `instance = new FrameTest(); instance.openFrames();` instead. But there are other issues with this code - as it was mentioned in the comments under @Vineeth answer below there is no `BorderLayout.START_END` in the _Oracle JDK_.

Comment: Btw, can't reproduce the issue with all possible `BorderLayout.*` constants on my environment (not _Mac OS_), so it looks like environment specific issue and we don't have environment description at all.

Comment: The OP has been edited, START_END was written incorrectly, what was meant was BorderLayout.PAGE_END

Comment: @kay As every one i was not able to reproduce it (oracle jre 1.8_121). But in case that you are using a custom component, the problem could be on it. Try to set `minSize`, `maxSize` and `preferredSize` on it.

Comment: @fhofmann I tried those as well, along with a lot of the other related threads I saw here. (tried repainting/revalidating all components and panels after that change as well) but it doesn't seem to get rid of that white bar.

Comment: Still not reproduced it but I still believe that is something related to the component. Maybe you can paint the components background with different colors, or include some onClick that shows the component name and size. Debug may help as well :).

Comment: did you render opengl content on jpanel or not?

Answer (score 0):

SwingUtilities has a method for refreshing components, it should work for any JComponent,

```
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(Component componentToRefresh);
```

the code snippet above shows how to use that method, to insert it into your code, do:

```
public void setDimensions(boolean smallType) {
     int width = 765;
     int height = smallType ? 530 : 577;
     clientFrame.setSize(width, height);
     SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(clientFrame);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since Frame is added to Panel, try to call validate() on the panel.

Comment: i tried that also, validating AND revalidate() on clientFrame, clientPanel, clientFrame.getContents()

Comment: Shot in the dark, can you try to revalidate first then a [repaint](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#repaint(long,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) might do the trick...

Comment: Check this solution out...seems like the same problem you have, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37840360/white-bars-in-the-right-and-bottom-sides-of-a-canvas-after-a-joptionpane-confirm?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Trying both solutions in that thread did not work for me either for some reason

Comment: BorderLayout.START_END? Didn't know that even existed?! I'd try to use `            clientFrame.getContentPane().add(client_panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);`